# Sync files between AWS S3 and Rackspace cloudfiles

Tags: amazon-s3, rackspace-cloud

I am looking for a solution for syncing files between AWS S3 and Rackspace Cloudfiles on a regular basis. Preferably, using a third party service or low maintenance self-hosted solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [File Conveyor](http://fileconveyor.org/).

> File Conveyor is a daemon written in Python to detect, process and sync files.

Basically it will detect file changes, process them as you define, and then sync via defined transports. S3 and CloudFiles are both supported tranports. One caveat. You might have to sync to a physical disk first.

You could look at useing a FUSE for s3 or cloudfiles to help with this.